# Problems reading number given endianness (C to Javascript)

Tags: node.js, c, endianness

I am coding a parser (Writing NodeJS code) where the C spec defines LittleEndian system for the byte order, where the most significant bit is on the right end.

At some point in the description, they say this:

> Most significant bits (MSB) is on the left, the information is encoded in a 32-bit unsigned integer as follows
> 12bit (year) | 4 bit (month)...

So I see logical to parse the bit this way (pseudo code)

```
const number = readUint32BE(data) //unsigned integer 32 bits
const year = (number >> 20)
```

Does that make sense logically ?

However I get the wrong numbers, and I get the right numbers (reasonable years) If I do:

```
const number = readUint32LE(data) //unsigned integer 32 bits
const year = (number >> 20)
```

Any help to understand what am I thinking wrong please?

Comment: I'm not seeing any difference between your two code fragments?

Comment: @SteveSummit yes right the comment in the first line please

Comment: A comment says, at best, what you *want* some code to do.  But without seeing the code, we can't say anything about what it *does* do!

Comment: It sounds like the documentation you've been given is wrong / misleading.

Comment: @SteveSummit the code comments are mine. Is it correct to say that MSB in the left indicates Big Endian and MSR indicates little endian? Yes I believe there are a couple of errors in the comments from the original C code for some reason.

Comment: If you have a 32-bit unsigned integer, then yes, `number >> 20` is a fine way to extract its 12 most-significant bits.  Now, in any integer, the "most-significant bits" are , quite simply, the most-significant bits.  Saying "Most significant bits is on the left" is pretty meaningless.  So maybe just ignore that part of the documentation.

Comment: @SteveSummit You are right, It does not make sense now that I think of it. Once you read with the right endianness then it is always like that.

Comment: The terms "big endian" and "little endian" apply (a) when you're reading or writing multibyte integers to files, and (b) if you're inspecting the bytes of multibyte integers in memory on a byte-addressable machine.  But if you're doing arithmetic on a 32-bit integer, no matter what, `(number & 0x01)` is the least-significant bit and `(number & 0x80000000)` is the most-significant bit.

Comment: @SteveSummit so if I understand correctly, once I read it the data in the correct endianness I just think of it mostly as a standard binary number. Feel free to add an answer. Thank you.

Comment: "LittleEndian system for the bits order" is poor wording.  Better as "LittleEndian system for the _byte_ order".  Byte endian differs from bit endian.  Bit endian is rarely a concern with typical code issues yet comes up in serial transmission.

Comment: Thanks. I am an absolute beginner and didn't find those concepts that easy to remember @chux-ReinstateMonica (that was my wording, not a textual quote.)

Comment: @MahNeh Please post an example of the data being parsed.

Comment: @MahNeh "However I get the wrong numbers" --> better to append  example input, output expected and output seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are reading data in from the outside, byte order truly matters.
Examples:

```
/* read two-byte integer, little-endian: */
unsigned short i1 = getc(ifp); x |= getc(ifp) << 8;   

/* read two-byte integer, big-endian: */
unsigned short i2 = getc(ifp); y = (y << 8) | getc(ifp);
```

If you are using a byte pointer to access the bytes of an integer in memory, byte order truly matters.
Example:

```
uint32_t x = 0x04030201;
unsigned char *p = &x;
printf("%02x\n", *p);
```

On a little-endian machine, this prints `01`.  On a big-endian machine, this prints `04`.  On a little-endian machine, the pointer `&x` literally points at the "little end" of the 4-byte integer `0x04030201`.

But when you're doing *arithmetic*, and when you're doing bitwise operations, on values that are multibyte quantities, byte order does *not* matter.  These operations all take place on the full value, *not* on the individual bytes of the value.  Examples:

```
uint32_t x = 0x04030201;
unsigned char msbyte = x >> 24;      /* always most-significant byte */
unsigned char lsbyte = x & 0xff;     /* always least-significant byte */
unsigned char lsbit = x & 0x01;      /* always least-significant bit */
```

In the original question, given that "the C spec defines LittleEndian", the pseudocode

```
const number = readUint32LE(data)
```

would be correct, and the alternative

```
const number = readUint32BE(data)     // WRONG
```

would be incorrect.  However, once the `number` has been read in correctly, it's now a proper value, and byte order considerations no longer apply.  The stipulation "Most significant bit is on the left" is unnecessary and somewhat misleading.  Code like

```
const year = (number >> 20)
```

to extract the 12 most-significant bits is perfectly correct.